# Reflection. Вызов методов объектов реализующих IDynamicMetaObjectProvider

Tags: c#

Долго искал как можно вызвать через рефлексию методы ExpandoObject или наследников DynamicObject. На просторах интернета нашел библиотеку 
[Dynamitey](https://github.com/ekonbenefits/dynamitey/wiki/UsageReallyLateBinding#dynamic-impromptuinvokememberobject-target-string_or_invokemembername-name-params-object-args)  . Но она не работает с .Net Core

Comment: А зачем вам рефлексия? Почему не просто скастить в `IDictionary<string, object>`?

Comment: Вот вам [официальный пример](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_6) (найдите _Enumerating and Deleting Members_).

Comment: IDynamicMetaObjectProvider реализует не только ExpandoObject. DynamicObject, JObject тоже.

Comment: А IDictionary<string, object> у меня реализовано через IReflect. Но там нельзя обратиться к DynamicObject, JObject

Comment: @Serginio перед тем, как давать целых два ответа, стоит полноценно оформить *вопрос*. Сейчас из текста вопроса совершенно непонятно, в чем именно вас проблема. Т.е. ок, у вас есть объект с реаизацией IReflect. Почему бы вам не вызвать GetMembers?

Comment: У IReflect должны быть описаны все методы. Но я могу и не реализовывать GetMembers как в  примере во втором ответе

Comment: Мало того DynamicObject сам может быть оберткой над чем то. http://infostart.ru/public/457898/

Comment: @PashaPash У меня нет проблемы. Просто я долго искал решение и нашел. И решил им поделиться

Comment: @Serginio это хорошо и приветствуется, но вам стоит описать решение чего вы искали. Т.е. ваше решение слишком сложное для ExpandoObject. Для полноценной реализации IReflect тоже есть решение попроще. Т.е. вы привели решение, но не привели конкретную проблему, которую пытаетесь решить (т.е. проблема же в том, что у вас есть кастомная и неполная реализация IReflect, с которой вы зачем-то работает через IDynamicMetaObjectProvider). Вдруг для нее есть более простые решения.

Comment: Мою ветку удалили. На самом деле это для решения следующих задач https://habrahabr.ru/post/304482/  https://habrahabr.ru/post/304542/

Comment: @PashaPash кстати я и в своей разработке активно использую https://habrahabr.ru/post/307188/   Обращу внимание на несколько моментов. Конструкция:

document.QuerySelector<IHtmlAnchorElement>(rowSelector);

 На 1С выглядит так:

HtmlAnchorElement=ъ(ъ(document.in(IHtmlAnchorElement.ПолучитьСсылку())).QuerySelector(rowSelector));

 Я использовал зарезервированное слово in Для создания потомка DynamicObject, в котором сохраняются объект и дженерик аргументы, а затем через TryInvokeMember получаем имя метода и параметры и находим нужный метод и выполняем.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Долго искал решение для Динамиков (IDynamicMetaObjectProvider) нашел решение
https://gist.github.com/jflam/777574
https://github.com/mgravell/fast-member/blob/master/FastMember/CallSiteCache.cs

На основании сделал для разного рода DynamicObject

```
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder;
using System.Dynamic;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
namespace Тестовый
{
   public class DynamicInvoker
    {
       public static object InvokeMember(object target, string methodName, params object[] args)
        {
            var targetParam = CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.None, null);
            CSharpArgumentInfo[] parameterFlags = new CSharpArgumentInfo[args.Length + 1];
            System.Linq.Expressions.Expression[] parameters = new System.Linq.Expressions.Expression[args.Length + 1];
            parameterFlags[0] = targetParam;
            parameters[0] = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Constant(target);
            for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
            {
                parameterFlags[i + 1] = CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.Constant | CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.UseCompileTimeType, null);
                parameters[i + 1] = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Constant(args[i]);
            }
            var csb = Binder.InvokeMember(CSharpBinderFlags.None, methodName, null, typeof(DynamicInvoker), parameterFlags);
            var de = DynamicExpression.Dynamic(csb, typeof(object), parameters);
            LambdaExpression expr = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda(de);
            return expr.Compile().DynamicInvoke();
        }

        public static object GetValue(object target,string name)
        {

            CallSite<Func<CallSite, object, object>> callSite = CallSite<Func<CallSite, object, object>>.Create(Binder.GetMember(CSharpBinderFlags.None, name, typeof(DynamicInvoker), new CSharpArgumentInfo[] { CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.None, null) }));

            return callSite.Target(callSite, target);
        }
        public static void SetValue(object target, string name,  object value)
        {

                CallSite<Func<CallSite, object, object, object>> callSite = CallSite<Func<CallSite, object, object, object>>.Create(Binder.SetMember(CSharpBinderFlags.None, name, typeof(DynamicInvoker), new CSharpArgumentInfo[] { CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.None, null), CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.UseCompileTimeType, null) }));
                callSite.Target(callSite, target, value);
        }


    }
}
```

И вызов

```
void ВывестиСвойство(object target, string ИмяСвойства)
        {
            textBox.AppendText(ИмяСвойства+"="+DynamicInvoker.GetValue(target, ИмяСвойства).ToString() + Environment.NewLine);

        }
        private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            dynamic res = new ExpandoObject();
            res.Имя = "Тест ExpandoObject";
            res.Число = 456;
            res.ВСтроку = (Func<string>)(() => res.Имя);
            res.Сумма = (Func<int,int,int>)((x,y) => x+y);

            textBox.Clear();
            textBox.AppendText("ВСтроку="+DynamicInvoker.InvokeMember(res, "ВСтроку").ToString()+Environment.NewLine);
            textBox.AppendText("Сумма=" + DynamicInvoker.InvokeMember(res, "Сумма", 1, 2).ToString() + Environment.NewLine);

            ВывестиСвойство(res, "Имя");
            ВывестиСвойство(res, "Число");

            DynamicInvoker.SetValue(res, "Имя","Новое Имя");
            DynamicInvoker.SetValue(res, "Число","768");

            ВывестиСвойство(res, "Имя");
            ВывестиСвойство(res, "Число");

        }
```

Проверил на .Net Core. Работает. В скором времени выложу компоненту с поддержкой объектов поддерживающих IDynamicMetaObjectProvider

Answer (score 0):

Так же можно использовать и наследник DynamicObject

```
   class TestDynamicObject : DynamicObject
    {

        public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, object value)
        {

            return true;
        }
        // получение свойства
        public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
        {
            result = binder.Name;
            return true;
        }
        // вызов метода
        public override bool TryInvokeMember(InvokeMemberBinder binder, object[] args, out object result)
        {
            var res = new StringBuilder("{0}(");
            var param = new object[args.Length + 1];
            param[0] = binder.Name;
            if (args.Length > 0)
            {
                Array.Copy(args, 0, param, 1, args.Length);
                for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
                {
                    res.AppendFormat("{{{0}}},", i + 1);

                }

                res.Remove(res.Length - 1, 1);

            }
            res.Append(")");

            result = String.Format(res.ToString(), param);
            return true;


        }
```

И пример вызова например из 1С

```
Тестовый=ъТип("TestDllForCoreClr.Тестовый, TestDllForCoreClr, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null");
    Тест=ъ(Врап.Новый(Тестовый.ПолучитьСсылку()," Свойство из Конструктора"));

    // Это аналог структуры, но с поддержкой методов
    РасширяемыйОбъект=ъ(Тест.ПолучитьExpandoObject());

    Сообщить("ВСтроку="+РасширяемыйОбъект.ВСтроку());
    Сообщить("Сумма=" + РасширяемыйОбъект.Сумма(1, 2));

    Сообщить(РасширяемыйОбъект.Имя);
    Сообщить(РасширяемыйОбъект.Число);

    РасширяемыйОбъект.Имя="Новое Имя";
    РасширяемыйОбъект.Число=768;
    // Добавим новое свойство
    РасширяемыйОбъект.НовоеСвойство="Новое Свойство";

    Сообщить(РасширяемыйОбъект.Имя);
    Сообщить(РасширяемыйОбъект.Число);
    Сообщить(РасширяемыйОбъект.НовоеСвойство);

    НовыйРеквизит=ъ(Врап.Новый("System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject, System.Dynamic.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"));

    НовыйРеквизит.Имя="Новый Реквизит";
    НовыйРеквизит.Значение=123;


    РасширяемыйОбъект.НовыйРквизит=НовыйРеквизит.ПолучитьСсылку();
    Сообщить(ъ(РасширяемыйОбъект.НовыйРквизит).Имя);


    TestDynamicObject=ъТип("TestDllForCoreClr.TestDynamicObject, TestDllForCoreClr, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null");

    ДинамикОбъект=ъНовый(TestDynamicObject.ПолучитьСсылку());
    ДинамикОбъект.УстановимЛюбоеСвойство="Чего то там";
    Сообщить( ДинамикОбъект.ПолучитТоЧтоПередали);
    Сообщить(ДинамикОбъект.ПолучитТоЧтоПередалиСПараметрами(1,3.45,ТекущаяДата()));
    Сообщить(ДинамикОбъект.Ъ(1,3.45,ТекущаяДата()));

     Сообщить(Тест.ПолучитьАтрибутыПараметра());
     Сообщить(Тест.СравнитьАтрибуты());


 //  product=ъНовый("Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject, Newtonsoft.Json, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed");
 product=ъНовый("Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject, Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed");

   product.ProductName = "Elbow Grease";
   product.Enabled = true;
   product.Price = 4.90;
   product.StockCount = 9000;
   product.StockValue = 44100;
   DecompressionMethods= ъТип("System.Net.DecompressionMethods, System.Net.Primitives, Version=4.0.11.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a");
   //                                                          'System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

   JArray=ъТип("Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray, Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.0.11.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed");
   массив=ъ(Врап.Новый(JArray.ПолучитьСсылку(),"Real","OnSale"));
   product.Tags =массив.ПолучитьСсылку();

   Сообщить(product.ToString());
```

К сожалению Newtonsoft.Json под .Net Core не работает ToString() так как использует библиотеку System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives которой в .Net Core нет