# Можно ли (как?) ускорить рефлексии?

Tags: c#, .net, рефлексия

Есть ли возможность ускорить рефлексии?

Я для примера накатал вот такой код

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var sw = new Stopwatch();
        var ec = new ExampleClass();
        // Variant 1
        sw.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
            ec.IntProp = i;
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        // Variant 2
        sw.Restart();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
            ec.GetType().GetProperty("IntProp").SetValue(ec, i, null);
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        // Variant 3
        sw.Restart();
        var prop = ec.GetType().GetProperty("IntProp");
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
            prop.SetValue(ec, i, null);
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Вариант 1 использует чистую декларацию

Вариант 2 использует рефлексию, но каждый раз получает тип элемента и объект свойства (дескриптор)

Вариант 3 получает тип и объект свойства единожды и работает раза  в 1.25-2 быстрее, чем метод 2. То есть в бою я могу кэшировать дескрипторы свойств и использовать их. Хотя мне не очень это нравится, к тому же ускорение не существенно.

Результаты тестов примерно такие

4

400

300

Есть ли еще способы ускорить рефлексии?

Comment: Как-нибудь [так](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22532571/system-reflection-performance)?

Comment: @eastwing, а чем это отличается от варианта 3 в моем примере?

Comment: Лучше всего конечно Expression, но и вариант с dynamic  тоже не плох. Еще есть варианты с кэштрованием FastMember http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/544736/reflection-%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d1%83%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%85-idynamicmetaobjectprovider

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться компилированными выражениями (System.Linq.Expressions):

```
var p1 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(ExampleClass));
var p2 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int));
var body = Expression.Assign(Expression.Property(p1, "IntProp"), p2);
var setter = Expression.Lambda<Action<ExampleClass, int>>(body, p1, p2).Compile();
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
    setter(ec, i);
```